# FormText cannot display HTML entities

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm trying to get a standard `FormText` to display HTML entities like &, < and > in Eclipse 4.8:

If I use them as is I get the following exceptions:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid The entity name must immediately follow the '&' in the entity reference.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Argument not valid The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup.
```

I assume that means I should be using HTML entities for these special cases. The documentation suggests the same:

> When configured to use formatting XML, the control requires the root element form to be used and requires any ampersand (&) characters in the text to be replaced by the entity &.

It's easy to implement a test case now:

```
    FormText formText = new FormText(parent, SWT.NONE);
    formText.setForeground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_INFO_FOREGROUND));
    formText.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_INFO_BACKGROUND));
    formText.setText("<html><p><b>HTML works as expected.</b></p><p>The problem are: Entities like &amp; &lt; &gt;</p></html>", true, false);
```

The thing is: it won't work. Neither do HTML entities like `&#38; &#60; &#62;`.

The result looks something like this:

[image: entities shown as they are]

That's obviously not what I want. I tried different versions of Eclipse to see if it this behavior was a bug, but since it's in Eclipse 4.7 and 4.8. I assume it's a configuration I'm missing.

In Eclipse 4.6. the output is exactly as I'd want it:

[image]

So the question is: how do I get the `FormText` to display HTML entities?

Comment: Probably bug [538689](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=538689) which is fixed in SimRel 2018-09 (Eclipse core 4.9)

Comment: @greg-449 Great! Indeed it does work with 4.9!